# Find a point (x,y) at a distance 'd' from a given point(a,b) and an angle theta in 2-D.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, rotations, angle

I am trying to find a point (x,y) that is at a given distance 'd' from a known point(a,b) at an angle theta. it would have been doable if I knew either x or y but both are unknown in this case and the angle (theta) may be clockwise or anti-clockwise in different situations. Also, the point (a,b) does not necessarily lie on the x-axis or the y-axis. this point lies on a given line at some angle from the true North.

Any hints on this problem would be really helpful. I have attached an image for better clarity.(point (c,d) is known).[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yquP3.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean by an angle from a point? An angle can be measured *from* an axis or a specified line or line segment in a defined *sense* (clockwise or counterclockwise). Otherwise, your question is ill-posed.

Comment: Hi @Deepak. thank you. I have made edits to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the standard process (requiring a number of steps).

Firsr, start with a change of axes from
[image]

to
[image]

and follow the steps shown. The formula for rotation can be found in many youtube video.